# Проблема перехвата нажатий клавиш

Tags: python-3.x, клавиатура

Как сделать чтобы модуль **keyboard** НЕ вычислял нажатие клавиш вне программы, а только в при работе в ней. Пример кода:

```
import keyboard

def enter(e):
    print(e.name)

keyboard.hook(enter)
keyboard.wait()
```